# Has the Self language seen use outside of the computer research community?

Tags: programming-languages, smalltalk, selflanguage

Are there any non-research groups or projects which have used the Self language in some capacity?

Comment: @skaffman the self tag doesn't seem to have anything to do with the self programming language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have browsed a lot considering this topic and found only research, no commercial application.

**However:** Self has certainly influenced beyond the research-community, most importantly by inspiration (JavaScript's prototype-object-system), people, UI (Morphic in Squeak and Lively) and JIT (e.g. the Just-In-Time-Compiler inside the Java Hotspot-VM)